# Why won't WebStorm allow me to run simulator?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webstorm

I'm teaching myself `React Native` but it seems like I ran into a minor problem.  I want to `Run` my app to see what my code does but it's not letting me.  It's greyed out, meaning, it's not clickable (Screen shot below).  I've looked around SO for this solution but can't find it.  Apologies in advance if this is a silly question.
[image]

Error after running `npm install`:

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/name/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/name/package.json'
npm WARN Garen No description
npm WARN Garen No repository field.
npm WARN Garen No README data
npm WARN Garen No license field.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Run** main menu, choose **Edit Configurations...**. Then, in **Run/Debug Configurations** dialog that opens, press **+** (`Alt+Insert`), select **React Native** from the list.
See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.2/run-debug-configuration-react-native.html, https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/12/developing-mobile-apps-with-react-native-in-webstorm/

Comment: Thank you, this almost works.  I'm getting that error after I run `npm install`.  I posted it in my original post.

Comment: this error means that you are running `npm install` in a directory that doesn't have package.json file:) This command installs dependencies listed in package.json. If this file can't be found, the error is thrown